# Scheduling application for scheduling tasks based on JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am using Glassfish. I actually want to connect two database at certain time **interval** and read data from one using jTDS and write to another database. I did it using timer in plain java. But is there any open source javaEE(or other web application) app based on quartz that can be used to create schedule and monitor it. 
I found [mySchedule](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/downloads/detail?name=myschedule-1.6.0.war) are there other's too.

Comment: My answer here applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762723/server-side-timer-in-a-jsf-2-application/13763254#13763254

Comment: @AkselWillgert I need some open source app that i can modify to schedule different task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended using [mySchedule](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/) . It has all the required and I could get started quickly.
User guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/wiki/MyScheduleUserGuide).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using Jenkins to control and monitor a small Java program or script to do what you want.  It's a build system, but can be used for any periodic task and can keep logs and such.  I dont believe it uses Quartz directly, but it supports many of the same features.

http://jenkins-ci.org/